# Does CQS mean one class for one query in the Commands?

Tags: design-patterns

In CQS, does the "C" (Commands) require one class per query; same with the Q.  That is the examples I have seen, but didn't see it really defined anywhere.  Also, I do not mean CQRS, only CQS.  I do not know where I'd use R at the moment, so I am only using CQS.

Edit:  What I'm saying is something like this:

```
class FindBusinessesThatMakeCars()
{
    public FindBusinessesThatMakeCars()
    {
    }
    public Manufacturer GetBusinessesThatMakeCars()
    {
        return myMancturerObject; //much logic left out for the question.
    }
}


class FindBusinessesThatMakeHouses()
{
    public FindBusinessesThatMakeHouses()
    {
    }
    public Manufacturer GetBusinessesThatMakeHouses()
    {
        return myMancturerObject; //much logic left out for the question.
    }
}
```

and so on.  Same with Commands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CQS Principle has nothing to do with classes. It is about methods.

It says that every method should either be a *Query* (i.e. be purely functional, referentially-transparent, side-effect-free) or a *Command* (have a side-effect but return no data, i.e. a `void` method), and that you should not mix the two.

That's it. There's nothing more to it.

Comment: Yes, but all the implementations I've seen had separate classes for the Commands and Queries.  That's why I was asking.  I don't know I've seen enough real implementations.  I've seen them on GitHub, but they seemed consistent in the examples, whether a school project or "real" application.

Comment: CQS and CQRS are completely different things. It sounds like you are talking about CQRS, despite the fact that you claim you aren't.

Comment: @johnny If having a single class for either a command or a query works for you, do that. Otherwise it's as Jorg says, the principle applies to methods/functions. You can have a class containing multiple methods, some of them representing queries and some commands. The reasons why you do not want commands to return anything is to be able to run them asynchronously if you ever decided to do so. To fire & forget them.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I didn't think I was because I wasn't talking about different datastores, only different Command and Query objects.

Comment: @DavidPacker You don't mean put the queries and commands in the same class though, right?  Still one class for query methods, one class for command methods?

Comment: @johnny No, I mean exactly that. CQS basically is if a method returns something it should not produce side effects by modifying additional properties. If you want to modify something then the method should return nothing. As I have said, you CAN have one class per command/query, but it's not necessary.

Comment: @JörgWMittag After reading more I think I see what you mean.  My understanding is cqRs does use different objects instead of only different methods.  That must have been what I have seen as well and got confused.

Comment: Returning void is just one of many ways of avoiding the issues here. One of the central requirements is to offer a complete set of query's that don't force you to change state to learn about state. Requiring that commands return void is a brain dead simple way to ensure a design does that. So would not allowing access to some information ONLY through a mutating command that returns. Returning void also avoids some side effect issues, not all, but it is also posible to return a value after a mutating operation and not cause multi-threading issues. It depends on what you're returning.

Comment: @johnny CQRS is so much more than just using a different objects for querying and writing. In CQRS you are likely to use two completely different infrastructures for each side.